# Does my motherboard support dual-core processors?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, computer-building, compatibility, computer-architecture

**Hi there!**

I'm very confused about my motherboard (ConRoe945PL-GLAN) It's manual says, that i can use **only some kind of ConRoe processors**. But some pages on internet says that i can plug in almost everything.

For ex.: [aria.co.uk](http://www.aria.co.uk/Products/Components/Motherboards/Socket+775+%28Intel%29/ASRock+CONROE945PL-GLAN%2FA%2FASR++Socket+775+Motherboard+?productId=33289) says that i can plug in even **Core 2 Duo**.

It would be awesome if i would not have to buy new motherboard!

Anyway, if my motherboard will **not let me to plug in Core 2 Duo**, should i buy **Pentium 4 (very cheap)** with 3,2 GHz and **insanely overclock it to have some performance** or buy new motherboard + new processor for big money?

THX for any answers! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your processor socket [**supports Core 2 Duo**](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=CONROE945PL-GLAN)

> LGA 775 for Intel® Core™ 2 Duo /
>   Pentium® D / Pentium® 4 / Celeron® D
>   processors

Edit: However make sure **it's a Conroe version**, but you don't have to pick a Pentium or buy a new motherboard.

Here's an [overview of LGA 775 compatible processors](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010340343%201051707842&name=LGA%20775) available on Newegg.com

Personally I would recommend the E8400, since it has a very good price quality ratio.

Comment: agreed.  clock for clock, the Wolfdales rival Corei7 in singlethreaded benchmarks.  The E8400/E8500/E8600 also overclock to unholy mid 4ghz speeds.

Comment: +1. Conroe is a Core 2 Duo CPU core variant. While an E8XXX processor should work, if your manual explicitly specifies "Conroe", it might need a BIOS update first. If in doubt, though, you would definitely be able to make a Core 2 Duo with an E4XXX or E6XXX model number work. It'll still be a huge performance boost from a Pentium 4, that no amount of sane overclocking could top.

Comment: But later on it says: *"This motherboard supports FSB800-CPU. If you plan to adopt Core™ 2 Duo CPU on this motherboard, you can only adopt Conroe 800 E4XXX processors."* So the OP should be careful not to use just any Core 2 Duo, it has to be a Conroe one (they say).